# Why can't I build pagodas in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I have the pagoda belief yet none of my cities let me purchase.  All of them have my religion and I have plenty of faith but it won't even give me the option.

Comment: Check that the religion definitely has the Pagodas belief, the religion is the majority religion in that city (more than half the population), the city doesn't already have a pagoda and you're on the buy menu.

Answer (score 12):

You can purchase a pagoda in a city if:

- The city's majority religion has the Pagodas follower belief- remember that the majority religion requires over half the population to follow it.
- The city doesn't already contain a Pagoda
- You have enough faith (though if you don't, the option will still appear greyed out).
- The city is not a puppet.

If all these are true, go to the buy menu in a city (you can't just build faith buildings) and the Pagoda will be there.

Comment: Slight note: Venice *can* purchase buildings in puppeted cities.